# .NET Framework v4 service running in X86 and X64

Tags: services, .net-framework

I've got two .NET Framwork services running, Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86 and Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64.
I'm using Windows 7 64 bits so I was wondering if I still need the X86 version considering the fact that I'm writing C# with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: If you want to be able to run x86 applications you need both services.

Comment: But does it need to be started with the OS or can I set its starting mode to "manualy"?